# How to indicate an array of different types in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, stored-procedures

I have this function, the problem is that being of type any all the methods (setString, setInt, ...) I get an error :(

```
fun execStoredProcedure(storedProcedure: String, params: Array<Any>?) : ResultSet? {
     try {
        val procedure: CallableStatement = this.getConnection().prepareCall(storedProcedure)

         if ( params != null ) {
             for ( (index,param) in params.withIndex() ){
                 when( param::class.simpleName ){
                     "String" -> procedure.setString(index+1,param)
                     "Int"    -> procedure.setInt(index+1,param)
                     "Double" -> procedure.setDouble(index+1,param)
                     "Date"   -> procedure.setDate(index+1,param)
                 }
             }
         }

        return procedure.executeQuery()

    }catch (e:Error){
        println("Error in storedProcedure: ${e.message}")
        return null
    }
}
```

```
O si alguien sabe una funcion para poder ejecutar cualquier stored procedure en Kotlin, mi profesor no enseña nada :(
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your `when` clause to do a class comparison rather than a `String` name comparison, you can take advantage of [smart casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts), and this should work (untested):

```
when(param) {
    is String -> procedure.setString(index+1,param)
    is Int   -> procedure.setInt(index+1,param)
    is Double -> procedure.setDouble(index+1,param)
    is Date   -> procedure.setDate(index+1,param)
}
```